# How to align two <ul> lists side by side?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align two bulleted lists side by side, however they are uneven in content the first one or the one on the left has 6 listed items and the second to the right of it has 5. The one with 5 starts at the 2nd point of the 1st list whereas I want it to start at the first evenly.

I have them in `div`s with their borders color'd to help see where things are lining up, I also have a gap between the two lists which I don't understand why it's there. My makeshift solution is to throw a `</br>` tag at the top but would like to know the actual way to solve this, thanks :)

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

div.SubjectsBox {
  border: solid orange 1px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

div.Subjects {
  border: solid purple 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="SubjectsBox">
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
      <li>Subject6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Final thing: Should I be using `em` instead of `%`?

Comment: `div.Subjects { vertical-align: top; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

div.SubjectsBox {
  border: solid orange 1px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

div.Subjects {
  border: solid purple 1px;
  display: table-cell;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="SubjectsBox">
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
      <li>Subject6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

try "table-cell" instead of "inline-block"

Comment: that solved it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

div.SubjectsBox {
  border: solid orange 1px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

div.Subjects {
  border: solid purple 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top; //this will fix your problem
}
```

```html
<div class="SubjectsBox">
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
      <li>Subject6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="Subjects">
    <ul>
      <li>Subject1</li>
      <li>Subject2</li>
      <li>Subject3</li>
      <li>Subject4</li>
      <li>Subject5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```